# Pandas stacked bar chart went wrong

Tags: python, pandas, stacked

I tried to change from normal bar chart to stacked bar chart but there's something wrong with the result.

Data:

```
                Total Monthly Actual Hours  Total Monthly Work Hours
Activity Month                                                      
Apr-19                            35381.25                     42592
May-19                            31722.50                     44528
Jun-19                            27708.50                     38720
Jul-19                            34283.50                     44528
Aug-19                            32225.60                     42592
```

This is the normal chart:

```
ax = dfWorkActual.plot(kind='bar')
ax.tick_params(rotation = 0)

for date, (p, q) in enumerate(zip(dfWorkActual["Total Monthly Actual Hours"],dfWorkActual["Total Monthly Work Hours"])):
    ax.annotate(f"{round(p,2)}\n({(p/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date-0.25, p*1.02))
    ax.annotate(f"{round(q,2)}\n({(q/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date, q*1.02))

plt.ylabel('Work Hours')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.title("Chart 5: (Total Monthly Work Hours + Total Actual Work Hours) vs Month", fontweight='bold')
```

[image]

This is the result after I added stacked=True:

```
ax = dfWorkActual.plot(kind='bar')
ax.tick_params(rotation = 0)

for date, (p, q) in enumerate(zip(dfWorkActual["Total Monthly Actual Hours"],dfWorkActual["Total Monthly Work Hours"])):
    ax.annotate(f"{round(p,2)}\n({(p/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date-0.25, p*1.02))
    ax.annotate(f"{round(q,2)}\n({(q/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date, q*1.02))

# for p in ax.patches:
    # ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(), 2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))

plt.ylabel('Work Hours')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.title("Chart 5: (Total Monthly Work Hours + Total Actual Work Hours) vs Month", fontweight='bold')
```

[image]

What I expected is the chart should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to plot the higher bar first followed by the lower bar. You have to plot them in a different color though, otherwise they won't show on the graph.

Code

```
fig, ax= plt.subplots()

col = dfWorkActual.columns[::-1]

color = ['y','b']

for i in range(0,len(col)):
    dfWorkActual[col[i]].reset_index().plot(kind='bar',ax=ax,x='Activity Month',color=color[i],figsize=(25,20))

for date, (p, q) in enumerate(zip(dfWorkActual["Total Monthly Actual Hours"],dfWorkActual["Total Monthly Work Hours"])):
    ax.annotate(f"{round(p,2)}\n({(p/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date-0.45, p*1.02))
    ax.annotate(f"{round(q,2)}\n({(q/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date-0.1, q*1.02))

plt.ylabel('Work Hours')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.title("Chart 5: (Total Monthly Work Hours + Total Actual Work Hours) vs Month", fontweight='bold')
```

Output

[image]

Alternatively, you can minus out the difference in a temporary df and then stack them, which I think is easier.

Code

```
df = dfWorkActual.copy()
df['Total Monthly Work Hours'] = df['Total Monthly Work Hours']-df['Total Monthly Actual Hours']

ax = df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,figsize=(18,15))
ax.tick_params(rotation=0)

for date, (p, q) in enumerate(zip(dfWorkActual["Total Monthly Actual Hours"],dfWorkActual["Total Monthly Work Hours"])):
    ax.annotate(f"{round(p,2)}\n({(p/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date-0.45, p*1.02))
    ax.annotate(f"{round(q,2)}\n({(q/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date-0.1, q*1.02))

plt.ylabel('Work Hours')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.title("Chart 5: (Total Monthly Work Hours + Total Actual Work Hours) vs Month", fontweight='bold')
```

Output
[image]

Comment: What I actually mean is: For example, 35381.25 (Actual Hours) and 42592 (Work Hours). I dont really want the orange bar to be stacked to be 35381.25+42592 to be around 78000 but actually I wanted that both of them to be like the one that I posted in the question (expected output)

Comment: @FirdhausSaleh Edited. Sorry I had read your question mistakenly just now.

Comment: Thanks @QuantStats it's perfect

Comment: @FirdhausSaleh Also see the alternative method of doing it by stacking their difference, which I think is easier.